# Github Actions and Variables

Tags: github-actions

The below snippet is representative of a workflow I have.  Everything works fine except I have been trying to find a way to substitute all references to "package1" with a variable.

Have attempted many options and either it doesn't substitute or throws a reference-type error.

Thoughts on how I can make this work?

I would like to set it one place and substitute everywhere it is used. I know I can set it in the job / steps and get those. I struggled with find a way to use in the paths.

```
name: TEST1
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push: 
    branches: [master, dev]
    paths:
      - "packages/package1/**"
      - '!packages/package1/file1.txt'
      - '!packages/package1/tests/*'  
jobs:
  Test1:
    uses: another_yaml...
    with:
      working_directory: "packages/package1"
      package: "package1"
      merged_branch: ${{ github.ref_name }}
    secrets:
      SECRET1: ${{ secrets.A_SECRET }}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? How would you apply a variable to your push-paths?

Comment: At which level(s) do you want to substitute this value? At the workflow, job or step level? All of them?

Comment: Response added to the description

Comment: I don't think you can use variables in the trigger section.